# ROC AUC Metric in KFold Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation, roc

What is the best way to use ROC / AUC as metric in Keras instead of 'accuracy', while doing a KFold validtation? I tried replacing 'accuracy' with sklearns 'roc_curve' and 'auc', but this did not work.

Also: How could I access the 'cross_val_score()' loops in order to plot the ROC-Curve?

Here is my code:

```
X = X.values
Y = Y.values

def create_baseline():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(82, input_dim=82, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=50, shuffle=True, random_state=True)
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)

print("Accuracy: %.3f%% (%.3f%%)" % (results.mean()*100.0, results.std()*100.0))
```

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by it did not work?  You did not get `roc_auc` scores in `results`? You want to plot the roc_curve for each fold?

Comment: I imported roc_curve from sklearn and replaced ['accuracy'] with it. I received the following error: Invalid metric: roc_curve. Actually I want to print out each folds prediction and the corresponding actual output for each fold. Furthermore I want to plot the overall ROC-Curve if that is possible. But most importantly for me it is to use roc as the metric and not the overall accuracy, since this generates a bad model in my case. I hope you can help. If you need more information, please ask! Thanks!